# Getting back to initial viewController from modally presented view

Tags: swift, view, navigation

I'am creating a food ordering app. I have four `view controller` in my `Tab bar`. I can add food to the `cartView (VC2)` from my `homeView (VC1)`. These two are in `Tab bar`. In my `cartView(VC2)` i have a button to open the `orderView` **modally** (this view is not in my `Tab Bar`.) After a successful order, i have a button in `orderView` to get back to my `homeView (VC1)`. but because `orderView` is presented modally I can't use `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`. How should I achieve this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `dismiss(animated:,completion:)` method to dismiss a presented `UIViewController` instead of poping since the `UIViewController` wasn't pushed into the navigational stack and cannot be poped.

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to dismiss presented screen after that you can use notifications for selecting first tab and popToRootViewController or you can define protocol in your orderView and fire it's method in dismiss completation.